# Explain this "hidden secret" of the gita by abhinava gupta

Tags: bhagavad-gita, abhinavagupta

[image]

So in abhinavagupta's commentary on the bhagavata gita called "gitartha samgraha" (link for pdf given at the end of the question), on page 125 ,which is also linked below, abhinavagupta is commenting and explaining a verse of the gita on chapter 4 and then he says "here i will stop revealing this secret ...." so can anyone tell me what "secret" he's talking about?

link to book  = https://in.yoga/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/boris-marjanovic-abhinavaguptax27s-commentary-on-the-bhagavad-gitagitartha-samgraha-indica-books-2004.pdf

Comment: He does make it clear the 'secret' can be revealed to those who have attained dīkṣā and become śiṣyas to ācāryas of proper paramparā. Therefore, when you attain dīkṣā under a proper ācārya of a proper paramparā, it would be revealed to you. Since, Abhinavagupta doesn't want to divulge the secret like that, no one (of proper paramparā) who knows it, would prefer to speak it out publicly too.

Comment: @Bingming ofcourse I see that , but I don't have access to diksha especially those types who are giving diksha of this "secret" of gita so my question basically was of somebody knows this just tell me.